# How to create dynamic Sqlite database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having list of string array by that I want to store all list items in SQLite database , size of my list of string array is varying every time when application runs.
so my question how to store string array values in an SQLite database  where my string array is dynamically changeable because string array values are coming from server.

I am new to Android development

Comment: does the number of column changes dynamically or they remain same

Comment: number of column remains same only values will increase

Answer (score 0):

If the number of column and their name does not change you do not need to create a dynamic table ,
create the table with application and then
you can do one thing first receive the the values in and array and then fire an insert query
with for loop

like

add this to button click event like

```
    (
          new View.OnClickListener()
          {
            @Override public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                     addRow();
                }
          }
    );
}

// function for insertion 


    private void addRow()
    {
        for(int i=1;i<arry1.length;i++){
            try
            {
                // ask the database manager to add a row given the two strings
                db.addValue
                (
                     arry1[i],
                     arry2[i],
                         arry3[i]
                );

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Add Error", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  
         }  


// data insertion


 public void addValue(String string1, String string2,String string3)
    {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Columns1,string1);
        values.put(Columns2, string2);
        values.put(Columns3, string3);

        // ask the database object to insert the new data 

        try{
            db.insert(TableName , null, values);
             }

    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

and you should read this tutorial for being familiar with database concepts

http://www.anotherandroidblog.com/2010/08/04/android-database-tutorial/

Comment: @MichellBak thanks for suggestion buddy ,it would be helpful if you please tell the area of improvement , it would be helpful for me